# python function arguments

Tags: python, function

I have a Python function that inputs a string and should output a path along with doing some other operations within the function.
So the function looks like this, where testcase is the input and path should be returned:

```
def generate_testcase(testcase,path)
    path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), testcase)
    return path
```

The function is a part of a package "regress" and is being called/used as:

```
import regress
testcase='xyz'
regress.main.generate_testcase(testcase,path)
print path
```

Now I am getting an error that I have not defined path

`NameError: name 'path' is not defined`

Comment: I don't know what this regress stuff is, but generally you do not need to put the return value in your function signature. If some function `f` takes a value x and returns a value y, the signature is `def f(x):`, not `def f(x,y):`.

Comment: The code you posted has syntax errors.  Please post a small but real example of code that you are actually running.

Comment: You're calling the function with a variable named "path".  Where is the incoming variable defined?

Comment: Post the code where you are calling `regress.main.generate_testcase()` ..

Comment: I have added added the code to hopefully have better explanation

Comment: You haven't defined the variables `testcase` and `path` before passing them into the function.

Comment: So I had defined "testcase" before the function. I need the function to return "path"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs because in your main script where you are calling - `regress.main.generate_testcase(testcase,path)` , you have not defined `path` yet. And that is exactly what the error tells you as well.

In Python, you do not need to pass in the argument that you need to return. You are not doing anything with the `path` variable passed in as argument, I am guessing you think its needed as `path` is returned from the function, but its not. Just remove it from the parameter list and then in the main script, make it so that path recieves the return value of the function. Example function -

```
def generate_testcase(testcase)
    path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), testcase)
    return path
```

Example main script -

```
import regress
testcase='xyz'
path = regress.main.generate_testcase(testcase)
print path
```